# Inductive proof of question regarding recurrence relations

Tags: algorithm, math, recurrence, induction

Currently, I am solving some problems regarding the algorithm, and one problem has become a pain in the butt.

Solve the following recurrence. Then, use induction to prove that your solution is correct.

T(n) = 3T(n/9) + n^(1/2), for n > 1,
and T(1) = 1 for n = 1.

Note that n is a power of 9 (e.g. 9^0,9^1, 9^2,…).

I will be really appreciated if anyone could help me out to solve this problem :(

Comment: Is "n1/2" meant to be "n/2," "n^{1/2} = sqrt(n)," or something else?

Comment: more appropriate to a math forum

Comment: n^(1/2)... sorry for the mistake

Comment: 90 is not power of 9. 81 and 719 are

Comment: Not programming-related -> off-topic on SO.

Comment: **HINT:** calculate the first few values (T(1), T(2), T(3), T(4),...) and factor them. Notice how the powers of three increase.

Answer (score 1):

[*Master Theorem*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Master_theorem_(analysis_of_algorithms)) states that if the problem is of form

[image], where [image],

then the solution is of form

[image] for [image].

Here we have *a = 3*, *b = 9*, *c = 1*, and *k = 1/2*. Since *b^k = 3 = a*, we conclude that the given algorithm's complexity is ***O(n^(1/2) log(n))***.

Now, I'm not entirely sure how this would be proven using induction, since the Master theorem gives definite proof for problems of such kind. Nevertheless, I hope this at least helps a little.